# SwiftUI NavigationPath append not working from viewmodel

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable

I'm trying to setup a push style navigation stack on SwiftUI using `NavigationPath` and `.navigationDestination` view modifier. However, the changes to the path performed from a view model is not being triggered. Can someone help me on what is going on?

Root View and the setup

```swift
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    
    func push() {
        path.append(RoutePath.viewA)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MainViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.path) {
            VStack {
                Button("View A") { viewModel.push() }
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationDestination(for: RoutePath.self) { route in
                switch route {
                case .viewA:
                    let viewModel = ChildAViewModel(path: viewModel.path)
                    ChildAView(viewModel: viewModel, path: $viewModel.path)
                case .viewB:
                    Text("View B")
                default:
                    Text("Not Implemented")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum RoutePath: Int, Hashable {
    case viewA = 0
    case viewB = 1
    case viewC = 2
}
```

Child View's implementation

```swift
class ChildAViewModel {
    internal init(path: NavigationPath) {
        self.path = path
    }

    @Published var path: NavigationPath
    func pop() { path.removeLast() }
    
    func pushB() { path.append(RoutePath.viewB) }
    

}

struct ChildAView: View {
    var viewModel: ChildAViewModel
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Button("Back") {
// When pop() is called from view model it does not work!
                viewModel.pop()

// When pop() is called from the binding variable, it works
//                pop()
            }
            
            Button("Child B") {
// push() called from view model does not work!
                viewModel.pushB()

// push() called from view for binding variable, it works.
//                pushB()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func pop() {
        path.removeLast()
    }
    
    func pushB() {
        path.append(RoutePath.viewB)

    }
}
```

I'm completely lost at why the push / pop functions called from the ChildViewA's viewmodel does nothing, where as same functions called from the view itself works alright.

I can alternatively, pass in root view's viewmodel as a routing parameter to the child views, but is that right?

Comment: The child path has no relationship to the main path but you should work though the Apple SwiftUI tutorials there is A lot wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

As lorem ipsum said, there are a lot of thing wrong with your code. You should study the basics of SwiftUI. Anyway, my approach here would be as follows:
First, declare MainViewModel as a StateObject at the root of your application, (ideally where the @main struc adhering to App is declared), and inject it as an environment object:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
            .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}
```

You can get rid of the ChildViewModel by the way.
Modify your MainVM to take care of all navigation by passing the function push the route to follow:

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    
    func push(_ routPathView: RoutePath) {
        path.append(routPathView)
    }
    
    func pop() {
        path.removeLast()
    }
}


enum RoutePath: Int, Hashable {
    case viewA = 0
    case viewB = 1
    case viewC = 2
}
```

And your views now would be like this:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MainViewModel
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.path) {
            VStack {
                Button("View A") { 
                    viewModel.push(RoutePath.viewA)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationDestination(for: RoutePath.self) { route in
                switch route {
                case .viewA:
                    ChildAView()
                case .viewB:
                    Text("View B")
                default:
                    Text("Not Implemented")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ChildAView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MainViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Button("Back") {
                viewModel.pop()
            }
            
            Button("Child B") {
                viewModel.push(RoutePath.viewB)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The @EnvironmentObject property wrappers looks for an injected object of that type. Remember to inject it into the previews too, otherwise, if your injecting it from the @main App struct previews will crash.

```
#Preview {
ContentView()
    .environmentObject(MainViewModel())
}
```

It's a lot cleaner and more concise, don't you think? Why having a ChildVM that would take care of the same things as the MainVM anyway?
Let me know if this sounds like a good solution to you!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It is very helpful. I've tried another way earlier where I instantiated `NavigationPath` as a `@State` variable in the first view and passed it along directly the view as `@Bindable` object and it seemed to have done the trick as well.

Previously having worked on these massive iOS projects written completely in mvvm / mvp architecture, I'm still transitioning my way into SwiftUI way of thinking and will take bit of time to get rid of. One down side I found with the `EnvironmentalObjects` is the unit testability with interface style can be very challenging.

Comment: As for SwiftUI learning materials, besides Apple's resources, have you come across good content with advanced topics surrounding architecture and common pitfalls to avoid etc.. 

Thank so much in advance for your help! @matbuompy

p.s. I will keep question active for few more days incase someone else wants to add their ideas.

Comment: I usually get updated by reading articles online on sites like these: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift - https://www.avanderlee.com/. Then I've also attended some courses on Udemy or Design+Code: https://designcode.io/courses/